# Splice array within array

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

How can I splice an array within another array?

I'm trying to create a game for kids in my class. Some kind of a trivia history question creator. How to splice the MasterArray so that I would get rid of sub-arrays (Hard-England and Medium-England) within the allEnglandArray. Because the "MasterArray.splice()" seem to be affecting - splicing only the allEngland array, or the allFrance array. But I need to get rid of those sub-arrays...

My code:

```
var Easy-England:Array = ["item1","item2","item3","item4","item5"];
var Medium-England:Array = ["item6","item7","item8"];
var Hard-England:Array = ["item9","item10"];
var allEngland:Array = [Easy-England,Medium-England,Hard-England];

var Easy-France:Array = ["item11","item12","item13","item14","item15"];
var Medium-France:Array = ["item16","item17","item18"];
var Hard-France:Array = ["item19","item20"];
var allFrance:Array = [Easy-France,Medium-France,Hard-France];


// the list of countries goes on and on and on... (Italy, Hungary, etc.)


var allStuff:Array = [allEngland, allFrance, etc.];
var MasterArray:Array;

// FUNCTIONS

// clear MasterArray - first I clear out completely the MasterArray

function clearMasterArray():void
{
    MasterArray.splice(0);
}

// update MasterArray - than I fill the MasterArray with data according to checkBoxes

function updateMasterArray():void
{
    for (var i:int = 0; i<checkBoxBlock.myCheckBoxes.length; i++)
    {
        if (checkBoxBlock.myCheckBoxes[i].selected)
        {
            MasterArray.push(allStuff[i]);
        }
    }
}    


// splice MasterArray - last thing I do is splice the items according to student's proficiency level, referred to as "studentPL".

function spliceMasterArray():void
{
    if (studentPL == 1)
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i<allStuff.length; i++)
        {
            allStuff[i].splice(5,5);
        }

    }

    if (studentPL == 2)
    {
         for (var i:int = 0; i<allStuff.length; i++)
         {
            allStuff[i].splice(8,2);
         }

    }

    if (studentPL == 3)
    {
        for (var i:int = 0; i<allStuff.length; i++)
        {
            trace("no need to splice");
        }
    }
 }
```

And after this I call those functions in another function in this order...

```
function creatorFunction():void
{
    clearMasterArray();
    updateMasterArray();
    spliceMasterArray();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of:

```
var allEngland:Array = [Easy-England,Medium-England,Hard-England];
```

try this:

```
var allEngland:Array = Easy-England.concat(Medium-England, Hard-England);
```

This way you will have a 'flat' array (no sub-arrays), so it will be easier to deal with.